# LDAP AD query. What does the dollar sign in OU=$Customer does

Tags: c#, filter, ldap, member, memberof

I am trying to get all the members of a group in two different Active Directories (AD) domains of the same company.

To do that I get first the full Distinguished Name (DN) of each group from the Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC) Attribute Editor as specified [here](http://activedirectoryfaq.com/2014/10/ad-attribute-editor-missing-make-search-visible/).

The first group DN is:

```
*CN=first-group,OU=organization-unit-name,DC=first,DC=company,DC=com*
```

The second group DN is:

```
*CN=second-group,OU=$Customer,OU=one,OU=two,OU=three,OU=four,DC=second,DC=company,DC=com*
```

Then I use the two following LDAP query filters in C# (I also tried them in ADUC).

For the domain ***first.company.com*** and the ***first-group*** I apply the following filter:

```
*(&(objectCategory=*)(memberOf=CN=first-group,OU=organization-unit-name,DC=first,DC=company,DC=com))*
```

And I get 123 Results as expected/

For the domain ***second.company.com*** and the ***second-group*** I apply the following filter:

```
*(&(objectCategory=*)(memberof=second-group,OU=$Customer,OU=one,OU=two,OU=three,OU=four,DC=second,DC=company,DC=com))*
```

However now I get only one result. in more detail myself. This is not what was expected.

I do know alternate ways to find the expected result in the ADUC by clicking in the Members tab once selecting the *second-group* but I need an LDAP filter to do it because I want to do get the results in C#.

Does anybody knows what the $Customer is doing?
What the dollar means in general in an LDAP filter?

I tried the filter without Ou=$Customer but it returns no results.

Thanks for the helping!

Answer (score 0):

There are two [LDAP Queries that will work for Microsoft Active Directory](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches):
Resolves all members (including nested) security groups (requires at least Windows 2003 SP2)

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

Or to retrieve only users:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

If you only want direct members, drop the ":1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:" from each query.

In a LDAP filter there the $ means "$".  (ie it is just a character)

Comment: Thanks for the reply about the dollar sign. It is clear now. However I still don't get why the group that has more members than me, shows such a DN entry which returns only when I apply the filter that I mtioned above.

Comment: Have you checked Permissions?

Comment: On the AD manager side you mean? If so no I didnt since I don't have access on that level of info. But I should have the right permission since I can retrieve this info on the ADUC GUI with my account credentials.